# how to package software with its dependencies as one binary

Tags: linux, package, packaging, software-packaging

in addition to providing the software via package managers, is there a way to provide the software with *all* its dependencies packaged into one for download. i.e one big binary.

The goal is for users without permissions or with dependency issues to simply download the big binary and run it out of the box.

Note: Software can already be installed via apt-get but I want to offer the option to download it whole

Comment: possible duplicate of [What’s the best way to distribute a binary application for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522990/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-a-binary-application-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating

rpm package for Suse/RHEL linux can be installed "rpm -ivh".

package (.pkg) in solaris and can be installed "pkg -d".

Comment: a .deb package is already available via apt-get with all its dependencies. The goal is to package it with its dependencies as one download